# Change in homepage by submit value by hackers how to prevent this?

Tags: html, css, security

I am trying to make one website for my school and i just started from basic to test
security of our website and it was observed that while getting this output from there
code if we put **Name: ../** and **Information : (any html code)** then it changes that page
into that html code which was injected. Is there any solution how i can prevent this 
problem so that i have much higher security.HTML code is

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Submit your form</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="Black" text="#FFFFFF" link="#FFF833" vlink="#FFF833">
<center><table width=600 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 align="center"><tr><td>
<font face="verdana" size=2><b>Use this form to submit your information to the website.<br /><Br>Note:Information will be stored online immediately but will not be listed on the main page until it has a chance to be looked at.<br /><br />
<form action="submit.php" method="post">Name:<br />
<input type="text" name="name">
<br /><br />Information<br /><textarea rows=15 cols=40 name="text"></textarea>
<br /><br /><input type="submit" value="add text"></form></font>
</b></td></tr></table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It depends entirely on how you're saving this user input...

Comment: But still how can someone just put's his own code and change our site homepage.

Comment: It depends entirely on how you're saving this user input...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have stated twice, it depends entirely on how you're saving this user input... wait, that's three times now XD

I'm going to guess your code is:

```
file_put_contents("submissions/".$_POST['name']."/index.html", $_POST['text']);
```

But if `$_POST['name']` is `../` then you are saving their submission to `submissions/..//index.html`... in other words you are overwriting the homepage of the site! And by allowing `$_POST['text']` to be dumped in there with no safety just lets anyone do what they want.

Instead, you should be saving these submissions to a database, referencing them by an ID number, and using something like `htmlspecialchars` to prevent input HTML from being processed.

Comment: You guessed right. actually the code is saving their submission. And don't worry i just think about it and finally got it. well no need to say it again finally i got it :D thanx

Answer (score 0):

you need to add some filters with your each field for the input because if you are not doing this then the chances of **XSS** (corss-site scripting) increases so whether you are taking input from user for suppose usernamd , password , email-ids etc always check is fields must cot contain html tag specially the **JAVA SCRIPT tag**. If you allowed JAVA script tag with the input it will case session hijacking so please check all thing before lunch on final domain and host . GOOD LUCK

Comment: Well nicely said and i find this very helpful and if it comes to hacks like XSS or any SQL injection then i have to prevent this from javascript or from php for sure and for that i have to learn these security measure.

Comment: SQLi (sql injection) , XSS are comain attack which found by several ways Like google dorks with your web site and there are many ways you can check your web sites for all the possible attack . And there are several ways for securing the sites you can find many on exploitdb.com.

Comment: Well thanks for the site and i know that to see the possible vulnerability of any site i use acunetix ... and if it come to security well i really need to work on it.